# How do I prevent second child from wrapping

Tags: html, css

```css
#parent{
    max-width:1100px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 40px;
}
#child0{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#child1{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child0">
        Hello0
    </div>
    <div id="child1">
        Hello1
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a simple html document, I tested with max-width but I don't understand it. When I reduce screen width, second `child1` breakins `child0` and it wraps down, then max-width is working, I want to do that when `child1` breaks `child0` starts its max-width, not after wrap.

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question, but it sounds like you need to use a media query to force your children to perform the way you want after your width goes below the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your second block width is getting 100% of the parent. It should get (100% - 200px). Also, you should discount the padding and border sizes with `box-sizing: border-box;`

```css
#parent{
    max-width:1100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 40px;
}
#child0{
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#child1{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    border: 1px solid green;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child0">
        Hello0
    </div>
    <div id="child1">
        Hello1
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, and one more question, is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yep, here is another approach using `flex-model`. In this approach the second block doesn't wrap never. https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/9j4rg05a/